# SQL - Why isn't my query working?

Tags: mysql, sql, associations, row

I have a PHP/MySQL application where I have users, groups, and rights :

- Each user can be in 0..N groups
- Each group can have 0..N users
- Each user can have 0..N rights
- Each right can be granted to 0..N users
- Each group can have 0..N rights
- Each right can be granted to 0,N groups

Here are my entity tables :

user_e :

- id
- login
- password
- etc...

group_e :

- id
- label

right_e :

- id
- label

And my association tables :

user_group_a :

- userId references user_e.id
- groupId references group_e.id

user_right_a :

- userId references user_e.id
- rightId references right_e.id

group_right_a :

- groupId references group_e.id
- rightId references right_e.id

Until now it's pretty straight forward, nothing really original.
My problem is that i want a query that can "Get the distinct rights that are either granted to a user of given ID or to any of the group that user belongs to". Or put it in another way : "The (distinct) union of a given user's rights and his groups's rights)

For example :

- group 1 has rights 1 and 2
- group 2 has rights 6 and 7
- user 1 is in groups 1 and 2
- user 1 has rights 2, 3, and 4

Then user 1 has rights 1 and 2 (from group 1), 6 and 7 (from group 2) and 2, 3, 4 (from hisself).
So in the end the query must return the rights 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7

So far i have the following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.*
FROM   user_e U
       LEFT JOIN user_right_a UR
              ON U.id = UR.userid
       LEFT JOIN right_e R
              ON R.id = UR.rightid
       LEFT JOIN user_group_a UG
              ON U.id = UG.userid
       LEFT JOIN group_right_a GR
              ON UG.groupid = GR.groupid
                 AND R.id = GR.rightid
WHERE  U.id = 1
```

But when i run it in my test database where i have put some test data (which i can provide if needed) it returns a single right with all attributes (id, label) set to NULL while it should return several rows.

What is wrong with this query ?

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT** : HERE is the data : http://www.fileden.com/files/2007/8/1/1314138/test.sql (exported by phpmyadmin)

Comment: there's no way to tell without the data

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to a .sql file that re-creates the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
select distinct united.rightid
from (
select UR.userid userid, UR.rightid rightid
from user_right_a UR
where UR.userid=1

union

select UG.userid userid, GR.rightid rightid
from user_group_a UG
join group_right_a GR on UG.groupid=GR.groupid
) united
where united.userid=1
```

Comment: At the first look it seems to be working, thanks for your help !